# Get substring in between two other strings?

Tags: c#

I am trying to get a string in between two sub strings, but I am running into an issue.

I am trying to use Selenium to automate a web test, and extract the profile ID from the javascript in the page source. I am running into an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`?

It doesn't matter with I'm searching for the correct or wrong values and passing them to `GetInbetween`, it throws this exception. I cannot see anything wrong with my code, so here I am.

Code:

```
var source = GetSource();
var username = "username1";

Console.WriteLine("Here: " + source.GetInbetween("window.__additionalDataLoaded('/" + username + "/',{\"logging_page_id\":\"", "\","));
```

Source (truncated for readability):

```
window.__additionalDataLoaded('/username1/',{"logging_page_id":"profilePage_10216","logging_page_username": "username1"})
```

Exception:

```
ArgumentOutOfRangeException 
Length cannot be less than zero. (Parameter 'length')
```

It throws the exception in this method

```
public static string GetInbetween(this string s, string start, string end)
{
    return s[(s.IndexOf(start) + start.Length)..s.IndexOf(end)];
}
```

LinqPad test:

```
void Main()
{
    var source = "window.__additionalDataLoaded('/username1/',{\"logging_page_id\":\"profilePage_10216\",\"logging_page_username\":\"username1\"})";
    var username = "username1";
    
    Console.WriteLine(source.IndexOf("window.__additionalDataLoaded('/" + username + "/',{\"logging_page_id\":\""));
    Console.WriteLine(source.IndexOf("\","));
    
    Console.WriteLine($"[{source}]");
    Console.WriteLine($"[{"window.__additionalDataLoaded('/" + username + "/',{\"logging_page_id\":\""}]");
    Console.WriteLine("Here: " + source.GetInbetween("window.__additionalDataLoaded('/" + username + "/',{\"logging_page_id\":\"", "\"."));
}
```

Comment: In your LinqPad code you pass `"\","` to `IndexOf` to get the result of 81, but you pass `"\"."` to your `Getinbetween` method.  Not the first one has a comma and the second one has a period.  If you pass the one with a period to `IndexOf` the result is -1.

Answer (score 2):

You might get this error if `end` exists in `s` **before** `start`. So try using `s.LastIndexOf(end)`.

Comment: @Milney It sure would throw exactly this error as I have confirmed using a .netfiddle (https://dotnetfiddle.net/zvCEGK)

Comment: @Milney If the slice was between say 8 and 3, the resulting length would be -5, which I assume could throw such an exception.

Comment: Using `LastIndexOf` returns everything after `start`.

Comment: Example: `profilePage_10216","logging_page_username": "username1"})`

Answer (score 0):

It says 'Length cannot be less than zero.' which means IndexOf is returning -1, which it does if the substring is not found in the search string... So you are looking for a substring which doesn't exist in the string. Make sure you have case-sensitivity correct, or use an IndexOf overload which ignores case.

Edit -- Your GetSource() method must not be returning the string you think it is returning... See, works fine explicitly searching that string:

[image]

Comment: Both substrings exist, I have manually confirmed this. Case sensitivity doesn't matter as the javascript is in the same case as the substrings in the code, also manually confirmed. I will try and debug the `GetInbetween` method.

Comment: @AAA - you confirmed it incorrectly, as it works fine for me - see my edit. Try doing var source = "" and putting it in explicitly. Your GetSource() function is obviously not returning the string you think it is

Comment: I used a string literal for source, and got these results from indexOf (first argument to GetInbetween and second): 0 and 81

Answer (score 0):

Passing a start index to `IndexOf(end)` like this seems to fix it.

```
return s[(s.IndexOf(start) + start.Length)..s.IndexOf(end, s.IndexOf(start))];
```

The final method looks like this:

```
public static string GetInbetween(this string s, string start, string end)
{
    return s[(s.IndexOf(start) + start.Length)..s.IndexOf(end, s.IndexOf(start))];
}
```

Comment: That would make no difference since in your example the index of `start` is 0.  More likely you ran this with the correct `end` value instead of the one with the typo in the code you posted.  You really should be checking if both IndexOf calls return -1 and determine how to handle that as well of the case of the `end` index coming before the `start` index plus the length.